# Have error while adding new elements to Eclipse Swing

Tags: java, swing, jframe, eclipse-indigo

I tried to add new elements to my java swing window by dragging the elements from the eclipse window. Am getting a error like this.\

Error As

```
line: 1 The import java.awt.BorderLayout is never used  
line: 2 The import java.awt.EventQueue is never used  
line: 4 The import javax.swing.JPanel is never used  
line: 5 The import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder is never used  
line: 6 The serializable class AdminJframeEdit does not declare a static final   serialVersionUID field of type long  
line: 12 The value of the local variable textArea is not used.
```

[image: This is the error am getting]

Comment: Have you tried to check all the things in that list of **"Possible Reasons"**? I'd start there. If all show no signs, then the last bullet point looks like it maybe the cause. Reinstall the WindowBuilder plugin

Comment: Also those things you point to as errors, those are not errors in code, but rather warnings. Maybe WindowBuilder is parsing them as errors. Anywho, I'd check all the possible problems and/or reinstall the plugin

Comment: Am new to java. Please can you help me, How to re install the window builder.

Comment: Code doesn't seams to have any error.

Comment: http://www.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/download.php

Comment: @peeskillet Have reinstall the window builder but still showing the same ERROR